# double pointer on a array and element of a table that points to a table

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I would like to know:

- how to point the elements of a table to an array of elements?
- How to make the operations on?

Here is a code that I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 4

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int *t[N];
    int tab1[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4},
        tab2[N] = {5, 6, 7, 8},
        tab3[N] = {9, 10,11, 12},
        tab4[N] = {13, 14, 15, 16};

    for (i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
        *t[i] = tab1[i]; 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *t[0]);
    }
}
```

When I run it, nothing is happening.

```
fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$ gcc -o test test.c
fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$ test
fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$
```

[i want to implement this !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj9l0.jpg)

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to do that? Why not use `int t[N][N];`

Comment: For me, it does something: it crashes.

Comment: I have a non-deterministic automaton. To transform it into a deterministic automaton, I will have states that correspond to a list of states from the transition table.
 Example: State: [0, 1, 2, 3]
state 0 -> [0, 1]
 state 1 ---> [2, 3]

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and reveal what output you expect.

Comment: Do you understand me now?

Comment: @fogangfokoa Well, if you think you have a good reason then .... 1) The second loop has to be deleted and replaced by `t[0] = tab1; t[1] = tab2; ...` and to access elements use the form `t[0][0]`, `t[0][1]`, and so on The last loop could be `printf("%d\n", t[2][i]);`

Comment: `*t[i] = tab1[i];` You did not allocate any memory for the pointers stored in `t`. Dereferencing and assigning something to it is UB.

Comment: tab = [1, 2, 3, 4]
I want element "1" to point to a tab (eg t = [2,3]). so that to browse t I go through tab [0].

Do you understand me?
Sorry if my english is bad!

Comment: @fogangfokoa no I don't understand. Just [edit]  your question and tell us what output you expect.

Comment: @fogangfokoa please tell us what exactly __should__ happen when you run the program you posted in your question. What do you think your program should print?

Comment: I posted an image for you to understand me

Comment: @fogangfokoa still not clear, please simply do as I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: Okay. i want that : t[0] contains tab1. Do you understand me @Jabberwocky

Comment: @fogangfokoa OK, I'm starting to understand, but still please tell me what you think your program should print

Comment: @fogangfokoa also what should `t[1]` contain ? `tab2` ?

Comment: `int t[N][N];` doesn't rule out non-deterministic data, unless the various dimensions change variably, in which case it is an array no longer. The picture on the hand-drawing shows the memory layout of a `int t[N][N];`.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run it, nothing is happening.
>
> ```
> fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$ gcc -o test test.c
> fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$ test
> fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$
> ```

[`test` is a shell build-in](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest).

To run a program called `test` being located inside the current work directory do:

```
fogang@les-tatates:~/tp_304$ ./test
```

Answer (score 0):

From the various comments you posted I guess (and I'm really guessing here) that you maybe want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 4

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int *t[N];
  int tab1[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    tab2[N] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
    tab3[N] = { 9, 10,11, 12 },
    tab4[N] = { 13, 14, 15, 16 };

  t[0] = tab1;
  t[1] = tab2;
  t[2] = tab3;
  t[3] = tab4;

  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      printf("%d ", t[j][i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

The `for` loop can also be written like this:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    int *temp = t[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      printf("%d ", temp[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
```

Or even simpler:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int t[N][N] =
  {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
    { 9, 10,11, 12 },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16 }
  };

  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    int *temp = t[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      printf("%d ", temp[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: // printf("%d ", temp[i]);    Don't work same for     printf("%d ", *temp[i]);

Comment: @fogangfokoa sorry, your comment is unclear (as the whole question BTW).

Comment: that's what i do, we understand already, The preblem is the printing data of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Jabberwocky's answer, you can even do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 4

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int tab1[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4},
        tab2[N] = {5, 6, 7, 8},
        tab3[N] = {9, 10,11, 12},
        tab4[N] = {13, 14, 15, 16};
    int *t[N] = {tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4};

  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: this line :  printf("%d ", t[i][j]); Don't works. It's exactly what i want to do !

Comment: Could you tell what *don't work* means here? **I** obtain values column wise here. What do **you** want?

Comment: When i compile and run the .out, i do not get the values.